# Ember.js: data-binding between controllers

Tags: data-binding, controller, ember.js

I'm trying to bind in the ApplicationController to the IndexController. [Here is my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/uB5tX/6/). To summarize, here is the binding I have in the Application controller

```
indexIsClickedBinding: "App.indexController.isClicked",

isIndexClicked: function() {
    alert("its changed to " + this.get("indexIsClicked") ) ;
}.observes('indexIsClicked'),
```

So, when the **isClicked** value in the IndexController is changed, but the indexIsClickedBinding doesn't do anything. Any suggestions whats wrong in my code ?

Cheers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Whilst the solution is simple, let me try and explain it. Please feel free to ask any questions if you're unsure.

You've bound to a property on an **instance** of `App.indexController`. However, this instance doesn't exist, because Ember.JS no longer places the instance of the controllers directly on `App`.

*It used to reside on `App` in previous versions of Ember, but not any more, because it's bad practice to reference a controller using its absolute name, since it creates [tight coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) between the controllers.*

That's why Ember.JS have other ways to reference to controllers. It is a common requirement to need other controllers in your current controller. Ember.JS have the following methods:

- `this.controllerFor()` in `Ember.Route`: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/
- **However, controllerFor has now been deprecated in favour of:**
- `needs` which tells the current controller which controllers it needs access to: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1731

Therefore, if we implement the `needs`, then your controller now has access to the other controller, as well as the properties it possesses: http://jsfiddle.net/uB5tX/7/

By using the `needs`, we have loosely coupled the controllers. We have referenced it by its name, and Ember.JS will look-up the controller for us. If we change `App` then we won't need to change anything, and if/when Ember.JS changes the behaviour of controllers, we shouldn't need to update our `needs` again, because when the behaviour changes, then the `needs` will also update, bringing back the correct controller.

Comment: thanks a lot!. So if you can't do App.someController, how does this now work in templates with #each, like: **{{#each App.someController}}** ?

Comment: There's no need to specify the `Controller` part, if you're using the `needs` approach. If `IndexController` `needs` `AnotherController` then in `IndexController` you'd simply reference it as: `controllers.another`. The same goes for views: `#each controllers.another`.

Comment: ok. One last situation. What about an ArrayController, how would you loop through that. In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/4ysxQ/) fiddle they still do it the old, and I can't get it to work in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/uB5tX/9/) fiddle

Comment: If you specify the `context` instead of the `content`, then you can just go straight for the properties (`name`, etc...) without having to specify anything before them: http://jsfiddle.net/uB5tX/10/ I'm not sure if you're creating instances just because it's a JSFiddle, but the unwritten Ember rule is that you create objects and not instances. For example, if you create the `App.IndexController` object then Ember will instantiate that controller when you move into the `index` route, as well as `IndexView` and `IndexRoute`.

Comment: ok, thanks about pointing out the unwritten rule. I've updates your (mine) jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/uB5tX/12/). Their is still a problems I think with this example. The view and the Array controller are still referenced as App.PeopleView and App.PeopleController (also, if you click on the names in your original example, nothing happens!) So I assume some Ember fundamentals are still violated

Comment: I've updated the JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/hbvAd/ Essentially you were trying to loop through the `App.PeopleController` object, not an instance. In the router we're forwarding the user automatically to the `App.PeopleRoute`, which allows Ember to automatically initialise `PeopleController`, `PeopleView`, and `PeopleRoute` for us. This allows us to do everything we want. We loop on the `controller` (`controller.content`) and then output each `person` by passing the `person` in as the `context` to the `Person` view of `App.PeopleView`. From there we output just what we need.

Comment: thanks!! I think this covers all the issue I had so far. I hope the EmberJs team will update the documentation soon! Cheers

Comment: I just noticed one thing that in your example, you set the content in PeopleRouter. Why doesn't this work if you already set it in the controller itselt ([like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hbvAd/2/))

Comment: I noticed a typo, but the result is the same: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/hbvAd/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use following syntax to access other controller's properties:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  index: Ember.inject.controller('index'),
  indexIsClicked: Ember.computed.alias("index.isClicked"),

  isIndexClicked: Ember.observer('index.isClicked', function() {
    alert("its changed to " + this.get("indexIsClicked"));
  })
});
```

However you need to make Ember initialize this controller first, so you actually need to call some computed property which depends on `index` (it will lazily initialize it). So, for example in template I use:

```
Is index clicked: <b>{{indexIsClicked}}</b>
```

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/8d22a0c79147a3783824)