# Is this the correct way for using Reveal with Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation

I tried to implement [Foundation Zurb's Reveal](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php) nicely in an Ember app, but I didn't succeed. Now with the pre.4 release I tried again and it turns out to be really easy, but I'm still wondering if I'm following the right patterns. If so, I hope this example will help you in your project.

Using:

- ember-1.0.0-pre.4.js

A working example can be found in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/ypzPx/).

I have a list of **Post** objects. Clicking on a list item will open a modal dialog and shows detailed information about the post.

To show the list, I create an Ember app and have a resource for my **Post** model:

```
window.App = Em.Application.create();

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'Lorem',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Ipsum',
    description: 'Fusce ante nulla'
}];

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create()
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('posts', {
        path: '/'
    });
});

App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Post.find();
    }
});
```

For the modal dialog, I include a `render 'reveal'` in the **application** template.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{outlet}}
    {{render "reveal"}}
</script>
```

I override the (by Ember on-the-fly generated) **RevealController**, since I need an **ObjectController** and I create a **reveal** template.

```
App.RevealController = Em.ObjectController.extend();
```

Since the content of my **RevealController** an instance of the **Post** model, I can put its properties in the template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="reveal">
    <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal large">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
    </div>
</script>
```

When I click on the title of a Post I want to set the content of the RevealController the instance of the Post. For this, I call the `openModal` event from the **posts** template and pass the current **Post** as its context:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
  <ul>
    {{#each controller}}
        <li>
            <a {{action openModal this}} href='#'>{{title}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Due to [target bubbling](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_target-bubbling) I can define the **openModal** event in the **ApplicationRoute** and I can set the content of the **RevealController** to the passed **Post** and eventually show the dialog:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    events: {
        openModal: function (content) {
            this.controllerFor('reveal').set('content', content);
            $('#myModal').reveal();
        }
    }
});
```

With my current knowledge of ember this feels like the right way to do, but I'm excited to hear if there are any improvements.

Comment: Beautiful code! It reads like a Wordsworth poem.

Comment: Thx, but according to [your answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760856/ember-js-data-binding-between-controllers/14762926#14762926), I need to use `needs` i.o. `controllerFor`. Haven't got this working so far.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote too much, so I replied properly below.

Answer (score 1):

I see absolutely nothing wrong with your approach. The `needs` is more about a controller relying on another controller, and what you appear to be doing is simply setting the `content` of an `Ember.ArrayController`. You'll need to change your implementation slightly to accomodate for `this.controllerFor` being **@deprecated** in Ember pre 5, but you can achieve this by:

- Specifying that the `PostsController` (and I assume others) require the `RevealController` using `needs`;
- Passing through the instance of `RevealController` to your `openModal` event (`{{action openModal this controllers.reveal}}`).

There are of course other ways to achieve roughly the same thing. However, the advantages I see are as follows:

- [You're using dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) in your events, which is great for testing, etc...;
- Your `App.ApplicationRoute` doesn't have the responsibility of having to find a controller;

With one disadvantage is that you're going to pass around the `RevealController` in a handful of controllers that are able to invoke Reveal. I don't particularly see this as a disadvantage though, because if you find yourself specifying the `needs: ['reveal']` a **lot**, then you can always create an abstract controller which your `ArrayController`s extend, since `needs` is a concatenated property (see `concatenatedProperties` in Ember's `Ember.ControllerMixin`):

```
App.AbstractController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['reveal']
});

App.PostsController = App.AbstractController.extend({
    // Since needs is a concatenated property, PostsController will have
    // access to 4 controllers: reveal, another, andAnother, andYetAnother.
    needs: ['another', 'andAnother', 'andYetAnother']
});
```

What do you think to this?

Also, the only non-Ember code you're really using that I can see is: `$('#myModal').reveal();`. Is there not a way in which you can place the Reveal code into the `didInsertElement` of the `App.RevealView`? And then in there you can do something like: `this.get('element').reveal();` or similar *(perhaps a sub-view?)*.

Comment: The use of `needs` is clear, but in my [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/y624y/) `controllers.reveal` seems `undefined` (see l36-40). Can't see what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Got it working with the latest commit of ember.js (post pre.4). Updated [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/Fv7fX/), still has pre.4, so it's only for illustration purposes :) Keeping `openModal` in the Route seems the right place, imo.

Comment: In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/bzeKS/) I override RevealView to encapsulate the call to the reveal-method. I think this is what you mean?